# MS graph user has multiple calendars with name 'calendar'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

we are using software to push events to calendars using MS Graph, however 2 of the users are getting errors saying the user has multiple calendars with the name 'Calendar'

When i use the MS graph explorer on
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I can see that there are 2 calendars setup the same, but with different ID's.

however in outlook and O365 online, and on the exchange admin console, i cannot see the 2 calendars only the one.

Is there somewhere that we can get to the calendars and either combine them or remove one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have not heard of combine calendars, you can delete it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Please share the Graph API call that you are using.

Comment: Yes the ids only will differentiate programmatically. To overcome the scenario, i would suggest you to rename the calendar names in a meaningful way in the UI. If its not showing in UI, it means the calendar folder might be hidden.

Comment: @CarlZhao, ill give it a go once back in the office with the user.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, the call is built into the software an external created, so i dont have access to this component, but thanks for the response

Comment: @Dev, ill have a go at renaming it, then will go for the delete if i cant resolve it, as the user doesnt use the calendar much.

Comment: Sure @Jason!! Sounds like a plan.

Comment: @JasonMurphy, Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting and accept it as answer. So it can be useful to others in the community :)

Comment: So i can now get access to the users MAPI using the tool, however cannot find the 2 calendars. In Graph explorer they are seen and i can see the ID's. Flying a little blind here, Can i adjust the names in the graph explorer online, or only the Mapi tool?

Comment: Hi Everyone. I tried to rename the calendar in MS graph explorer, however after using Get all calendars, i can see the two, but then one i can manipulate, the other it says when i try and patch anything to it, that the object doesnt exist in the store. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi Jason, same issue here with some users. The calendar objects returned are identical except for the ID, and the second ID returns the "object doesn't exist in the store" error when you try to use it for any other operations. My only thought was it was something to do with Microsoft Teams, as vaguely similar issue when listing emails and getting Teams messages linked to a non-working parent folder ID. Did you get any further with it?

Answer (score 1):

- Programmatically ids only will help you to differentiate. To overcome the scenario, i would suggest you to rename the calendar names in a meaningful way in the UI. If its not showing in UI, it means the calendar folder might be hidden.
- You updated that you will have a go at renaming it, then will go for the delete if you cant resolve it, as the user doesn't use the calendar much.

Comment: Hi Dev, Can we get this unanswered, as the issue is still there and i need help with it.

Comment: Looks like I have the same issue Dev, and you can't do anything with the second calendar as the ID doesn't work. It's only in the list calendars call that it shows up, identical but with a different, non-working ID. They are both in the same calendar group.

Comment: @JasonMurphy, wipolar - I would try the following in such scenario. (1) Observe what you notice in Outlook app. If the calendars available in a group, see if you can access both of them and it works. If its not working, better remove the one which is not working or throwing error  (2) Use tools like EWSEditor or MFCMAPI, i will validate which is the correct calendar folder (3) Now make the Graph API (share what you're using) to get the calendar, not the calendar group. Get the ID for the calendar, differentiate the correct and odd one. This will help you to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on one mailbox, and came here to post the resolution as I had to dig around and piece together a way to resolve it.

I'm sure there's a way to add the correct MS Graph permissions to an admin account to resolve this without logging in as the user, but I couldn't get that part right so here's what I did:

- Took a backup of the user calendar just in case.
- Verified only one calendar named "Calendar" was displaying in Outlook.
- Have the user login to the MS Graph site as themselves.
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.
- If you need to verify the UUID for this user, GET their UUID by running the default query:
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
- GET the associated calendars with their mailbox, you can search "calendar" in the sample queries menu to find "GET all my calendars" or you can just paste this in and run the query:
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars

You may need to click "Modify permissions" and consent to the permission to read calendar items. If so, you'll receive a notification in the MS Graph query.

- With this, I found two calendars named 'calendar', but only one of them was marked as "isRemoveable":true,
  Note down this UUID
- Again this command may prompt to give additional permissions, but using the reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http I ran the following command:

Choose DELETE in the drop-down, append the command /me/calendars/{CALENDAR UUID} and run it.

You will receive a confirmation message that almost looks like an error. [Green-colored response "No Content - 204"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cemp4.png)

- At this point, test the sync again. The user had no ill-effects from this as the offending calendar wasn't even in use/visible in Outlook.